# Shiny apps won't launch in RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I just installed R 4.1, RStudio 1.4, and the Shiny package. I'm trying to launch the most basic Shiny app using the green "Run App" button :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  'Hello world'
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I get nothing. The console shows the final line, followed by a blank output line :

```
> runApp('Projects/Shiny tutorial/main.r')
```

Plus the R session cannot be terminated.
My default browser is Firefox, and I'm running Windows 10.
Any idea what may be wrong ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this bug in R-4.0.5, shiny-1.6.0 on win10

Comment: You are right. There seems to be a problem with R 4.1. I downgraded to R 4.0.5, and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are running this in RStudio, what does Firefox have to do with it? I thought RStudio defaults to its internal browser for shiny apps (I don't normally use the RStudio IDE, so I'm not as proficient with it, though I did test this in it). If you have relevant `options(.)` in play here, it would be useful to provide those. (As a starting point, please post the output from `options("shiny.launch.browser", "shiny.port", "shiny.host", "shiny.testmode")`, others might be found [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/shinyOptions.html).)

Comment: Unable to reproduce in RStudio 1.4.1717 & R version 4.1.0, though admittedly running on OS X 10.14.6 (Mojave) rather than Windows.  Agree with @r2evans about the irrelevance of Firefox.

Comment: @r2evans You can change that behaviour to go straight to whatever browser you have set by default.

Comment: I think my comment on the default internal-browser was premature (knowing about `"shiny.launch.browser"`). Ultimately I feel like the downgrade to 4.0.5 is not satisfactory, since now we don't know what the culprit was. @gitSomeCoffee, perhaps you can raise an issue at RStudio about this?

Comment: FWIW, I'm on R 4.1, Rstudio 1.4, and shiny 1.6, and cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also found this to be an issue.

I tried to run:
runExample("01_hello")
in RStudio, R version 4.1.0, on Windows and nothing appeared at all.

Downloaded earlier R version 4.0.5 (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/) instead and worked perfectly too.

Answer (score 0):

***If the previous answer does not work for you, here is an alternative**

I had the exact same problem and found the solution. I tried Shiny for the first time and was not able to run an app localy. To provide context I had the 4.0.3 version of Rstudio and upgraded to 4.1.0 (sometime in the past year). I tried to run the " old geyser " Shiny app example and console was stuck on a runApp message or " Loading required package: shiny"

I found another thread that suggested to revert back to Rstudio 4.0.5 (and so I did), but I was having the same problem.

Finally, solution came from Winston Chan and was link to a mismatch in the libraries built and Rstudio built. Take the time to read the post and it will show you how to upgrade all your librairies to your Rstudio built version

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upgrade-R.html

Comment: 4.1.0 is the version of R, not RStudio